# Can a density matrix correspond to two different pure states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I have an equation of the form

$|\psi_1><\psi_1| = |\psi_2><\psi_2|$

This is equating two density matrices - also note that such an outer product can be formed on LHS and RHS. I believe the same density matrix can correspond to different mixed states. But can the same density matrix correspond to different pure states? i.e., can $|\psi_1> \neq |\psi_2>$? OR must they be equal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can differ by a phase, which will cancel out of the outer product, but other than that they must be equal.  Also, a mixed state is entirely determined by its density matrix, so in fact the same density matrix cannot correspond to different mixed states.

Comment: Sometimes people use "mixed state" to mean a probability distribution over pure states, with the density matrix defined as the expectation of $\left|\phi\right\rangle\left\langle\phi\right|$. In this case different mixed states can have the same density matrix.

Comment: Those are not different mixed states, but different ensemble realizations of the same mixed state, leading to identical  observable statistics.